# Jacobian Invariant

Tags: reference-request

I'm trying to find an on-line source for the "Jacobian Invariant" of four points on a line.

The cross-ratio depends on the order of the points, while this one doesn't.

I've done several Google searches and can't seem to find anything.

Does anyone know of a good source off-hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commonly used name is $j$-invariant. See [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/BEARDSLEY/node4.html) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant) (you will have to read a little to realize that they are talking about the same thing!)